# Pandas: frequency of an element in two groups of columns

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have a DataFrame `data` laid out like this:

```
Observation     A_1    A_2    A_3    B_1    B_2    B_3
Obs1            yes    no     yes    no     no     no
Obs2            no     no     no     yes    yes    yes
Obs3            yes    yes    yes    yes    yes    yes
```

The goal: calculate the frequency of all observations marked "yes" that are:

- only in "A" samples
- only in "B" samples
- In both groups

EDIT: This means that I need to exclude, for the first two counts, the observations that contain "yes" for *both* the A and B group (see third line).

I thought about using `groupby`:

```
grouper = data.groupby(lambda x: x.split("_")[0], axis=1)
grouped = grouper.agg(lambda x: sum(x == "yes"))
```

But I have counts divided by row, which is not what I want.

What would be the best couse of action here?

EDIT: As requested, more information on the output. I'd like something like

```
Frequency of valid [meaning "yes"] observations in group A: X
Frequency of valid observations in group "B": Y
Frequency for all valid observations: Z
```

Where X, Y, and Z are the counts returned.

I'm not caring for this specific output for the individual observations. I'm interested in values across all of them.

Comment: Could you include your desired output?  I'm not entirely sure what your intended result is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [129]: a = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3']

In [130]: b = ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3']

In [131]: ina = (df[a] == 'yes').any(axis=1)

In [132]: inb = (df[b] == 'yes').any(axis=1)

In [133]: ina & ~inb
Out[133]:
Observation
Obs1            True
Obs2           False
Obs3           False
dtype: bool

In [134]: ~ina & inb
Out[134]:
Observation
Obs1           False
Obs2            True
Obs3           False
dtype: bool

In [135]: ina & inb
Out[135]:
Observation
Obs1           False
Obs2           False
Obs3            True
dtype: bool
```

Counting can be done using value_counts: (ina & inb).value_counts()[True]

Comment: The first two lines will also include groups where both "A" and "B" have "yes" in their groups. I've added an explanation to the post to make this clearer. Regardless, this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not clear on whether you want `yes    no     yes    no     no     no` to count as 1 or 2.  The closest thing that I've ever needed looks something like this:

```
>>> df
             A_1  A_2  A_3  B_1  B_2  B_3
Observation                              
Obs1         yes   no  yes   no   no   no
Obs2          no   no   no  yes  yes  yes
Obs3         yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes
Obs4         yes  yes   no   no   no   no
>>> y = (df == "yes").groupby(lambda x: x.split("_")[0], axis=1).sum()
>>> y
             A  B
Observation      
Obs1         2  0
Obs2         0  3
Obs3         3  3
Obs4         2  0
>>> which = y.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index[x > 0]), axis=1)
>>> which
Observation
Obs1             (A,)
Obs2             (B,)
Obs3           (A, B)
Obs4             (A,)
dtype: object
>>> y.groupby(which).sum()
        A  B
(A,)    4  0
(A, B)  3  3
(B,)    0  3
```

or maybe simply

```
>>> which.value_counts()
(A,)      2
(A, B)    1
(B,)      1
dtype: int64
```

depending on your goal.